# KerasRegressor DeprecationWarning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I got this warning after creating a KerasRegressor object in google colab.

```
<ipython-input-216-4b2bcf00bc05>:2: DeprecationWarning: KerasRegressor is deprecated, use Sci-Keras (https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras) instead. See https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html for help migrating.
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_cnn_model, verbose=0)
```

I have installed scikeras and import KerasRegressor (`from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor`) but all in vain. So, how to fix this problem?